# Apply ArrayList Contains Method to DataRow

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am confused with `Contains` method of `ArrayList` in C#.  I have the following code, does the line `UniqueRecords.Contains(dRow)` return true when there are duplicate rows in my table?

I wrote the input as:

```
DataRow sourceRow = myTable.Rows[1];
myTable.ImportRow(sourceRow);
```

so it has duplicate rows,
but `UniqueRecords.Contains(dRow)` doesn't return true. Any help?

```
ArrayList UniqueRecords = new ArrayList();
ArrayList DuplicateRecords = new ArrayList();

foreach (DataRow dRow in myTable.Rows)
{
    if (UniqueRecords.Contains(dRow))
    {
        DuplicateRecords.Add(dRow);
    }
    else
    {
        UniqueRecords.Add(dRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, you really shouldn't be using `ArrayList` post C# 1.1.  Use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayList` class will use the `Equals` method of the objects in question to compare them.  It so happens that the `Equals` method of `DataRow` doesn't actually compare the values of all of the columns in the row, it just compares the reference to that row.  This means that two different rows with the same data are not "equal" according to that type, and consequently `ArrayList`.

You can create an `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` that is capable of using your own definition of equality, which can then be used by a `List<DataRow>` that has an additional overload of `Contains` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>`.  Better yet, you could use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, as it can do such searching much quicker than a `List`.

In fact, in this particular case, you don't even need to write the comparer yourself from scratch, one already exists in the language: [DataRowComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955.aspx).  It is specifically designed to give value-based equality, which is what you want.

Comment: Hi Servy, I wrote my own comparator, but it seems like it doesn't function very well. Can you please have a look? I learnt C# from yesterday and feel confused.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on how ArrayList compares two objects in its list. When this data structure ask a comparator to compares two objects' references (for reference type objects) so because your two supposedly-identical rows have different references they are not perceived equal by the comparator, although they have same values in each column.

Comment: This isn't the behavior of `ArrayList`.  `ArrayList` simply uses the `Equals` method of the objects themselves; it is those objects that define what "equality" means.